# Elementary OS 7 - File Manager - wrong default application for PDF

Tags: pantheon-files, files, file-management

When I download the files on my computer, I have a problem with files extensions. For example: its impossible to open PDF files with one-click - I have to click "Open with" and select application (For example Document Viewer or Google Chrome).

The File Manager ignores default application

Its very nuisance thing since I am dealing with PDF files a lot.

Do you know how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select "Document Viewer" in the "Other Applications" dialog with "Set as Default" ticked.  After that, PDF files should automatically open with "Document Viewer" when double-clicked.  You *must* use the "Other Applications" dialog with "Set as Default" ticked - if you just select from the Open in submenu then the default app is not changed (the document opens with the selected app on a one-off basis).

An alternative method is to select the PDF and choose "Properties" from the context menu (secondary-click) or press `<Alt>Enter` to bring up the "Properties" window. There you can see a "Opens with" combobox which sets the default app.

Note that you must *double-click* the PDF to open it (or select it and press `Enter`).  Single-click activation for non-folders has been discontinued.

Comment: I tried it of course :) Unfortunately this option does not work. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce it on my install of Elementary 7. I noticed you had "Sublime Text" showing as the default app for PDF which is a but strange as when I opened a PDF with that app it did not show intelligible text.  However, I was able to change the default app back to Document Viewer with no problem.  You could try the terminal command `mimeopen -d <name of a pdf file>` I guess.  This allows you to choose a new default app.  If you have to enter a command then for the default elementary pdf viewer enter `flatpak run org.gnome.Evince` because it has been flatpak'd

Comment: You could also check the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.  It should contain a line `application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop`.  Check the document that you are trying to open has this mimetype.